# Thread.sleep stopping entire function android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, function, delay

I have a java function that I want to delay in the middle.

```
frombox.setText(simpchi[rannum] + "\n[" + pinyin[rannum] + "]");
String meaning = meanings[rannum];
try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
tobox.setText(meaning.replace("/", "\n"));
```

I want the frombox's text to change, then after 0.5 seconds,  the tobox's text to change.

However, when executing this, the entire function delays, then the frombox and tobox's text changes at the same time.

What am I doing wrong? Sorry if this is really simple; I'm very new to java.

Comment: What is it with Thread.sleep() today?  Just wrote this in another question. To understand sleep(), you must understanding threading. sleep should not be used just to cause a delay. There are plenty of threading methods to cause code to pause and execute at a later time such as postDelayed(). sleep() is used to yield processing resources to the CPU so that it will not time slice (or multitask) your thread when you do not need it to execute. For example, you are waiting for a deadlock to resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call `Thread.sleep()` in the UI thread. **Never!**
What you should do:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
    public void run(){
        tobox.setText(meaning.replace("/", "\n"));
    }
}, 500); // 500 ms
```

or simply **(Credits to zapl)**:

```
tobox.postDelayed(new Runnable(){ 
    public void run(){
        tobox.setText(meaning.replace("/", "\n"));
    }
}, 500); // 500 ms
```

This way the 2nd settext will be delayed and also ran in the UI thread.

Comment: You don't even need a `new Handler()` you could just call [`tobox.postDelayed(Runnable...)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)